# Error:Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, openid

I know that question is already asked but none of the solutions worked for me.
Can anyone please help me with this. I m just a beginner in spring.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openid4java/consumer/ConsumerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:892)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openid4java/consumer/ConsumerException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:64)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  

  <display-name>WeeklySummary</display-name>

  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-    class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kratin" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <!-- Default converters -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />



<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.kratin.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <openid-login>
        <attribute-exchange>
              <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" />
              <openid-attribute name="fullname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson" />
              <openid-attribute name="first" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" />
              <openid-attribute name="last" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" />
        </attribute-exchange>
    </openid-login>
    <logout />
</http>

<!-- In our example we need to specify own UserService, to keep all logged-in users in the memory storage -->
<beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="demoAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>       
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="demoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <!-- property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/ -->
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.kratin.service.InMemoryUserDetailsService"/>

<!-- Handler to receive success openId response and create new user --> 
<beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.openid.ext.OpenIdAuthenticationHandler" 
            class="com.kratin.controller.DemoAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>
```

login.jsp:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Spring-Security-Step2 Sample Web-Application</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
 <h1> Login with OpenID </h1>
 <a href="j_spring_openid_security_check?openid_identifier=https://www.google.com  /accounts/o8/id">Login via Google</a><br></br>
 <a href="j_spring_openid_security_check?openid_identifier=http://www.yahoo.com">Login via Yahoo</a><br></br>

 <form name="myOpenIdForm" action="j_spring_openid_security_check" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="openid_identifier" value=""/>
<input type='text' name='my_open_id' value=''/>.myopenid.com
<input name="submit" 
       type="submit" 
       class="rsButton" 
       value="Login via MyOpenId"
       onClick="onMyOpenId();"/>
 </form> 

 <form name="googleAppsForm" action="j_spring_openid_security_check" method="post">
Login into Google Apps Domain
<input type="hidden" name="openid_identifier" value=""/>
Google Apps Domain: <input type='text' name='google_apps_domain' value=''/>
<input name="submit" 
       type="submit" 
       class="rsButton" 
       value="Login into Google Apps"
       onClick="onGoogleApps();"/>
 </form>

 <form name="openIdForm" action="j_spring_openid_security_check" method="post">
Login via any Open ID Provider
<input type='text' name='openid_identifier' value=''/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="rsButton" value="Login via OpenID"/>
</form>

 <script>
   function onMyOpenId() {
var myOpenIdName = document.myOpenIdForm.my_open_id.value;
document.myOpenIdForm.openid_identifier.value='http://' + myOpenIdName +    '.myopenid.com';
} 

function onGoogleApps() {
var googleAppsDomain = document.googleAppsForm.google_apps_domain.value;
document.googleAppsForm.openid_identifier.value='https://www.google.com/accounts  /o8/site-xrds?hd='+googleAppsDomain;
}


   </script>
    </sec:authorize>

  <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">

  DemoUserDetails currentUser =    (DemoUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

  <%-- OpenID: <%=currentUser.getUsername() %><br></br>
  Email: <%=currentUser.getEmail() %><br></br>
  Full Name: <%=currentUser.getFullName() %><br></br> --%>

  <a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
  </sec:authorize> 
  </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the root cause :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException

Add jar for this file

Comment: Thanks for this. I got similar error and I have totally missed the root cause at the bottom until I saw this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Exception for Class not found in your class path.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException
```

You have to put openid4java jar in your class path.
you can get it from 
https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/downloads/list

Comment: After adding openId4java jar now i m getting exception i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487252/caused-by-org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-error-creati