# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Instantiation of bean failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, openid

I'm basically trying to implement openId in spring which will allow user to login through goggle and extract their emailId, name and save in data base

After adding openid4java jar, now I'm getting the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with     name 'org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer] while setting bean property 'consumer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:273)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.<init>(ConsumerManager.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer.<init>(OpenID4JavaConsumer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 39 more
```

Library:

```
activation-1.0.2.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collection-2.1.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
ehchache-1.2.3.jar
hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.3.1.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.jar
hibernate-search-3.0.0.GA.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
jackson-all-1.9.11.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jstl.1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
luncene-core-2.3.2.jar
luncene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
openid4java-0.9.8.jar
persistance-api-1.0.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-step2-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan-2.6.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The class org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException is part of httpclient jar. I guess you missed to include that.

Comment: hey thanx, I updated my library,now I m getting exception: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Spring_Hibernate_Demo] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Answer (score 0):

Add latest httpclient.jar into the classpath. You can download it from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).